# Show scrollbar in Bootstrap 4 when content goes beyond window

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, scrollbar

So I'm using the new Bootstrap 4.1 and I'm having trouble with scrollbars not appearing.  When the page loads, it isn't big enough to need any scrollbars, but then the user does some searches and when the results show up, the page is bigger than the window.  You can scroll, but there is no scrollbar to see.  I've tried using `overflow-y: scroll`, but it doesn't work.

How do I get the page to show scrollbars when the content exceeds the vertical size of the window?

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchInput" aria-label="Search">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0 dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span id="searchType">All</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                &nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchButton" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main">

        <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
        <div class="jumbotron JumboHeaderImg">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-3">MAIN JUMBOTRON TEXT</span></h1>
                <p class="jumboTextStyle">SECONDARY JUMBOTRON TEXT</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Left Column with navbar search results  -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   Blah, blah, blah
                </div>
                <!-- Right column with details of item chosen from left column -->
                <div class="col-md-6" id="detailsContainer" style="display:none">
                    <h2>Details</h2>
                    <span class="detailsTable"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

        </div> <!-- /container -->
    </main>

    <!-- Custom Script -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Make sure youre targeting the actual element that you want the scroll bar to show up on. And make sure your css rule is not being overwritten by bootstrap.

Comment: Do you have `overflow:hidden` in body?

Comment: I don't have `overflow:hidden` anywhere and I am thinking that there is a CSS rule in Bootstrap that is doing this, but I have no idea where.  I have found that if you apply a height rule to a specific container, scrollbars will appear, but that isn't what I"m looking for.  I want the scrollbar to appear as needed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think this was an issue with the browser/computer.  I had an update/shutdown and when I got back into the page, the scrollbars started appearing automatically.  I didn't change the code with regard to trying to display scrollbars, but it seems to have solved itself.

Thanks to everyone who looked into this.